# Crop image from surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview, crop

I have to take a photo and crop it in my own camera view.
So I created custom surfaceview and draw a rectangle on it ( in onDraw() ).
Then, I have to crop image by that rectangle. The problem is that bitmap dimension is not the same as surface view dimension. 
How can i scale my rectangle to crop from bitmap?

Camera preview is fullscreen.